# Access host's smart card reader via Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, smartcard

I have a Windows 7 machine that has a smart card reader. I have an application running on that machine that can successfully read the contents of the card.

I have another Windows 7 machine that I use to remote into the machine that has the smart card reader. When I am using the remote connection, the application can no longer access the smart card connected to the host machine. I understand that due to Remote Desktop redirection, I can only use smart card readers attached to the client machine.

Is it possible to turn off this redirection?

Comment: Which remote desktop application are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound I am using mstsc. I have updated the title to specify "Remote Desktop Connection" for clarification.

Comment: Although I was unable to do this using RDP, I was able to use a different application as a workaround. Check out [link](http://www.realvnc.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible.

I have a similar problem and was looking for a solution. What I found was a [thread on social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/47972083-b9bd-49fd-8708-b296af81bda3/), where it says:

> [...] It’s not possible. If you are connected through RDP, then your session is redirected to the client machine and will not see readers connected to the RDSH.

Comment: I found a technical explanation here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2011/03/27/why-can-t-i-see-my-local-smartcard-readers-when-i-connect-via-rdp.aspx

Comment: @AndréStannek the above link is dead.

Comment: @Wollmich http://web.archive.org/web/20150922133959/http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2011/03/27/why-can-t-i-see-my-local-smartcard-readers-when-i-connect-via-rdp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `Smart Card` checkbox within the `Local Resources` tab is checked and RDP should pass the authentication through from the native system to the target system, using the native system's smart card reader. I currently use this method at work.

Comment: flag and ask a mod to convert this to a comment

Comment: OP is asking for the opposite.