# can't access smart card attached to remote computer via RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, smartcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access host’s smart card reader via Remote Desktop Connection](https://superuser.com/questions/543490/access-hosts-smart-card-reader-via-remote-desktop-connection)

I work in a location where im not allowed to have any electronic devices, I am however allowed RDP access and i can access my desktop computer at home

When im home I use my smart card reader to access various webpages for my employeer but when im on site and establish and RDP session the session doesnt show a smart card or a smart card reader as being attached

From my googleing so far it seems like RDP is redirecting the smart card reader proccess to my computer on site and ignoring the one thats local to the remote machine

I've seen answers but they are all geared to how to use the smart card at the local machine not at the remote machine

my question is:

how can i gain access to the smart card on attached to the remote laptop in my home?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to ever use the smart card on the remote machine unless you log into an already existing session. At least that is what I have gathered from the below snippit:

> The reverse is also true; if you RDP into a session from the start you
>   will never see any local smartcard readers as Winscard will detect
>   it’s running in an RDP session and no calls to Winscard will ever
>   reach the local PC/SC layer – everything will be redirected to the
>   connecting client.

The full article can be found here:
[Why can't I see my local smartcard readers when I connect via RDP?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2011/03/27/why-can-t-i-see-my-local-smartcard-readers-when-i-connect-via-rdp.aspx)

Comment: this could be my ignorance of RDP but i am logging into a machine that has already been started and has my session running. I believe im in my session because all the windows i leave up when i leave for work are up

Comment: @Crash893 - Please clarify all information in your question your statement makes no sense.